# The meaning of "about"

Tags: sentence-meaning

"There's something about this business that he is doing."

I am confused about the meaning of that sentence;

The sentence is saying "there is something about this business" until here everything is ok, but If I want to say "he is doing this business", I mean let's say he is a barber and I want to say "there is something wrong about his barber's business."

But,

There is an another meaning comes out about the sentence, "He is doing something about this business" I mean for now I am not talking about his job or else.

I don't know which meaning I should make?

I am not sure whether I could explain it well, I hope I could.

Thanks.

Comment: Your sentence doesn't quite make sense, all by itself. If you saw the sentence somewhere, please show the source. If you made the sentence up yourself, please explain simply what you are trying to say, Then people can suggest idiomatic ways of saying it.

Comment: Hi Jack, It was just an example from Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: Would you provide a link to that Oxford Dictionary, please?

Comment: The word **business** is often used to refer to a situation or activity (rather than a company or commerce), as in **funny business** or **unfortunate business.**  See the examples given at:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/business